# string contains valid characters

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

I am writing a method whose signature is

```
bool isValidString(std::string value)
```

Inside this method I want to search all the characters  in `value` are belongs to a set of characters which is a constant string

```
const std::string ValidCharacters("abcd")
```

To perform this search I take one character from  `value` and search in `ValidCharacters`,if this check fails then it is invalid string is there any other alternative method in STL library to do this check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`find_first_not_of()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/):

```
bool isValidString(const std::string& s) {
    return std::string::npos == s.find_first_not_of("abcd");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use regular expressions to pattern match.
library regexp.h is to be included

http://www.digitalmars.com/rtl/regexp.html

Comment: @Dead: Although its overkill here: *"RegExp is a C++ class to handle regular expressions."*

Comment: It is C++, but there's no need to bring in a non-standard library just to throw regular expressions at a problem that doesn't need them

Comment: @Crazy: To be entirely fair, I didn't read the link. I know that digitalmars is the site of the primary D compiler. There is, however, a regex header in TR1.